# Hard drive dded full of zeros won't allow install of new OS

Tags: hard-drive, ubuntu-server

I dded the hard drive with zeros as a simple way to clear out the sensitive data (yes, I'm aware there are better ways, but it was fast and easy). I am now attempting to install Ubuntu Server 12.04, but I run into an issue when I get to installing GRUB.

I issue grub-install /dev/sda and get a fatal error back.

My question is, are the two things related or "happy" coincidences?

If the two are related, is there a good way to solve the issue?

Comment: Filling a hard drive with zeros is enough, by the way. See [zero fill vs random fill](http://superuser.com/a/522765).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

attempts to install GRUB in the Master Boot Record (MBR) of `/dev/sda`.

The problem is: A freshly zeroed hard drive doesn't have an MBR!

To create an MS-DOS partition table / MBR, use the following command:

```
parted /dev/sda mklabel msdos
```

Comment: Doh! Thanks. Let me verify this works and the vote is yours.